# RubyMine issue: turbo-rails completion not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have the latest RubyMine, rails and ruby versions. Suggestions like "turbo_frame_tag" don't autocomplete and the error "Cannot find 'turbo_frame_tag" pops up.

Have you experienced the same problem? How did you fix it?

[image]

Comment: Could you specify your RubyMine's version? The general support has been added withing the following request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-30317/Rails-7-support-turbo-rails-completion

Comment: @Olivia My version is 2023.3 RC, but in this post is says it should've been released in 2023.1 - https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2023/03/rubymine-2023-1-is-out/

Comment: I've checked it in 2023.3, and it works fine. If your project is open source, it'd be great if you could share it. I was using a new plain Rails app with some configuration made according to https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails

Comment: Well, I reinstalled the OS(Ubuntu 22.x) on my computer and installed rvm,rails,... fresh (i reinstalled because I f**ed up pretty badly). So with my fresh install I managed to connect ruby with RubyMine and it works perfectly now.